# Виртуальная машина + сайт + apache

Tags: apache, ip, virtualbox, wamp

Здравствуйте. Есть следующая конструкция: шлюз на RedHat, сервер на windows server 2003. На сервере есть чистый Апач, отдающий 1 html страницу  и IIS, то есть установка mysql невозможна. Нужно запустить сайт на CMF Modx, то есть php+mysql, не удаляя IIS. Мне пришла идея установить виртуальную машину с WinXp на борту, там поднять необходимый WAMP. При обращении к сайту по адресу перебрасывать соединение на виртуальную машину, а там уже сервер. Кто подскажет, как правильно это сделать? Может есть хорошие мануалы, я в сети не нашёл.

**UPD 1.**На компе апач и сайт по адерсу 192.168.0.2 с одной страничкой.Сделал проброс портов в VirtualBox, сайт на локальном адресе 192.168.0.5. Проблема в том, что Апач почему-то перехватывает этот адрес и считает, что я обращаюсь к 0.2 и показывает мне эту страничку. Изменил проброс портов с 80 на 67 и обращаюсь 192.168.0.5:67 - отлично. сайт открывается, но эта приписка-порт в адресе портит всю систему. Как сделать, что бы апач не перехватывал этот адрес? Рылся в httpd.conf - нинашёл там ничего толкового. Listen 80ServerName 192.168.0.2:80

Comment: А почему вдруг нельзя установить mysql?Зачем крутить целый апач ради одной страницы?

Comment: Дело том, что там есть заглушка и IIS, который обрабатывает онлайн-расчёт какой-то. Соответственно там есть MsSql Server 2003. Как сказал мне человек, который это всё налаживал - они не уживутся и не надо даже пытаться. Я ищу обходной путь.

Comment: m$sql использует порт 1433, mysql - 3306. т.е. уживутся они без проблем. А чистый вариант, поставить отдельную машину с Apache'м PHP, MySQL, со своим блэк-джеком и шлюхами и делать проброс портов на шлюзе и использовать DMZ. Как то так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте что-то проще, чем WinXP, например, базирующееся на Linux. Настройка не займет много времени. Что касается перенаправления:

1. Вы можете настроить virtualbox чтобы использовать сетевой мост, тогда ваша виртуальная машина будет находиться в той же сети, что и сам сервер. Соответственно, если у вас есть ДНС сервер, можно очень легко добавить запись, указав IP нового сервера, тогда никаких перенаправлений делать не нужно.
2. Другой вариант, я правда, не знаю, как вам будет лучше. Сменить apache на nginx (он проще и быстрее). И не важно, менять или не менять, но затем настроить проксирование (об этом много информации в гугле). (Что-то наподобие front-end, как сейчас часто любят говорить).
3. Можете попробовать воспользоваться функционалом RRAS (тоже много информации в гугле). Хотя, насчет функционала здесь могу ошибаться, не имел с ним опыта работы большого.
4. [@timmer](/users/1140/timmer) тоже неплохую идею предлагает. Только операционную систему выбирайте попроще.

Comment: Я так и сделал. Вообще не столь важно, что поднимать. У меня есть Ubuntu Server с апачем, мускулем, пхп и пыхмайадмином. Проблема в обращенни, как их связать? Не нашёл ниодного мануала по этому поводу, только настройка сети, но как сделать перенаправление? Да, на сервере у анача так же нету php. Остаётся только машина.

Comment: А что мешает поставить PHP?

Comment: Если поставлю - легче будет поднять один лишь mysql на линуксе? Если апач вроде не новый, как не переустанавливая установить php и как отдельно поднять sql-сервер?

Comment: Если есть уже сервер со всем этим, воспользуйтесь [этим мануалом](http://www.linuxcenter.ru/lib/articles/networking/apache_proxy.phtml). Ваш уже работающий апач будет просто перекидывать все на существующий сервер.Или же поставьте просто php к Апачу. [Здесь мануал](http://php5.ru/study/install), там все просто, переустанавливать не придется. А если MySQL у вас уже есть на каком-то Ubuntu Server, присоединитесь к нему?

Comment: Большое спасибо, воспользуюсь 1 вариантом - прокси-апач.

Answer (score 1):

А почему нельзя на сервере поднять витруальную машину и на ней поднять только MySQL?

Comment: Возник порос:как поднять там мускуль что бы его было видно с десктопа?

Comment: В настройках соединения виртуалки - тип поставить сетевой мост, тогда виртуальная машина будет в той же сети, что и хост.

Answer (score 0):

> А почему нельзя на сервере поднять витруальную машину и на ней поднять только MySQL?

Хороший вопрос, а Вы знаете параметры сервера, win 2003 (x86) с m$sql как минимум раз в месяц нуждается в перезагрузке из-за утечки памяти.